# How to sync HTML fragments in JS without replacing everything?

Tags: javascript

I want to dynamically update my page based on HTML fragments that are rendered on the server. In a first simple approach I am simply fetching the fragments from the server and update the target via `.innerHTML`.

Unfortunately this causes two problems (which are basically the same):

1. When a user selects any text within the dynamic content, the selection will be cleared. Even, if the selected text did not change. This can be see in the example below: When selecting `foo`, it will be cleared after an update, but it does not actually change.
2. Any state that is attached to the elements gets deleted too. In particular the dynamic content of my page has some buttons which will show a loading indicator while the request is processing. It is okay for me, if the indicator is gone when the content changes, but the state being cleared every second makes the indicator useless.

My actual question is, whether there is an easy way to only update the elements that changed. Especially when when elements can be added, removed or reordered.

```js
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {  
  counter++;
 
  // assume this is fetched from the server
  content = '<ul><li>foo</li><li>'+counter+'</li><li>bar</li></ul>'; 
  
  document.getElementById("dynamic-content").innerHTML = content;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>my page</h1>
  <div id="dynamic-content">
      <ul>
        <li>foo</li>
        <li>0</li>
        <li>bar</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the server is returning the entire HTML of the element, you can't fix this. The server should just return what you want to update, such as the counter value. Then you can just update that element without touching other elements around it.

Comment: `"an easy way to only update the elements that changed"` – this is essentially the central value proposition of frameworks like React, Vue.js, etc. It's not a trivial problem. Consider even the sub-problem of user-selected text – what if the user selection overlaps with the changed content? What if content is inserted within their selection? What if part of their selected content is removed? etc

Comment: `The server should just return what you want to update, such as the counter value.` – If the lists gets longer and might reorder its elements this approach seems to get complicated too, I think.

Comment: `this is essentially the central value proposition of frameworks like React, Vue.js, etc` – Yes, looks like it. I did not yet take a look into those Frameworks, because they appeared very heavy, but I think I need to evaluate them closer.

Answer (score 1):

Depends upon what you want to replace, and knowing how to target that.  Here I did a totally artificial example of a partial replacement.

- I would do this in a promise not an interval
- You need to know what you want to do - here I show how to pick a sub-section out of what was (fake) returned and use that for example.

```js
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  counter++;
  const newDiv = document.createElement("div");

  // assume this is fetched from the server
  let content = '<ul><li>foo</li><li class="counter-thing"><span class="new-count">' + counter + '</span></li><li>bar</li></ul>';
  newDiv.innerHTML = content;
  let newc = newDiv.querySelector(".counter-thing").innerHTML;
  console.log(newc);
  let dy = document.querySelector("#dynamic-content >ul");
  let x = dy.querySelector("li:nth-of-type(2)");
  console.log(x);
  x.innerHTML = newc;
  // another way to put some text in (be careful of HTML here)
  document.querySelector('.example-two').dataset.content = counter;
}, 3000);
```

```css
#dynamic-content>ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}

.foo-me {
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
}

.new-count {
  background-color: #FF44FF44;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.example-two[data-content]:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>my page</h1>
  <div id="dynamic-content">
    <ul>
      <li class="foo-me">foo</li>
      <li>0</li>
      <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

Fake out another way to replace content:
<div class="example-two" data-content="Some content goes here."></div>
```

Comment: Interesting that the first example does not break the selection when the counter gets updated.

Comment: Lots of imperfection here including the use of that global counter in the anonymous function that should be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple library called [idiomorph](https://github.com/bigskysoftware/idiomorph), which does pretty much what I want. Generally there are multiple library for this use case and they describe themselves as DOM "morphing" libraries.

So instead of

```js
document.getElementById("dynamic-content").innerHTML = content;
```

I just have to do

```js
Idiomorph.morph(document.getElementById("dynamic-content"), content, {morphStyle:'innerHTML'});
```

Additionally I have to put `id` tags on every element, but this is easy in my case.